# Web Sockets not working for SSL, NGINX and Node JS

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket

Quick breakdown -

Dev environment works properly. SSL Cert on local server, nginx configured for proxy pass on 443 traffic.

```
    location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

for some reason, version 1.1 never works (always tosses an error)

Again, Dev environment works properly.

Production environment is giving me the following error:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://website.com/sockjs/421/fin4cg38/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

I use a load balancer which has the SSL cert on it and we enforce SSL through our application.

Now, I checked the configuration of NGINX and I have it as follows:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.website.com;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/sites-error.log;
return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;

}

server {
listen       80 default_server;
server_name  _;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
# proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
# proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
# proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

The way its set up is anything on 80 goes to 443, etc etc.

If I uncomment the proxy_set_headers, our sign up breaks and the chrome console doesn't show any errors.

error log has this:

```
2014/07/13 18:15:16 [error] 16175#0: *93 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.189.245.5, server: _, request: "POST /sockjs/421/wq2dqb2w/xhr_send HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/sockjs/421/wq2dqb2w/xhr_send", host: "website.com", referrer:   "https://website.com/signIn"
2014/07/13 18:15:42 [error] 16487#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while     connecting to upstream, client: 10.189.245.5, server: _, request: "GET     /sockjs/120/95m6dozn/websocket HTTP/1.1", upstream:     "http://[::1]:3000/sockjs/120/95m6dozn/websocket", host: "website.com"
2014/07/13 18:16:12 [error] 16487#0: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while     connecting to upstream, client: 10.189.245.5, server: _, request: "GET     /f1be3f98162c975fdc9524a0a222f9a02cc6dcde.js HTTP/1.1", upstream:     "http://[::1]:3000/f1be3f98162c975fdc9524a0a222f9a02cc6dcde.js", host: "website.com",     referrer: "https://website.com/signIn"
```

I'm not really sure what's going on. Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: What is was? I have a very similar issue, could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162490/express-ws-doesnt-handle-call-when-deployed-to-vps-server