# express-ws doesn't handle call when deployed to VPS server

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, websocket

I have back-end written using node.js + express with express-ws depedency.

Locally everything works like it should. Previously it was deployed to red hat open shift, also haven't had any problem. Yesterday I bought VPS configured it and deployed there. Everything works except websockets.

I have nginx with enabled SSL that has the next lines in config related to the server

```
server {
  listen       ipaddresshere:80 default;
  server_name  _;

  location / {
      proxy_pass  http://ipaddresshere:8080;
  }

  location /ws {
      proxy_pass  http://ipaddresshere:8080;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

  }
}
```

I have other config places but they were generated by VestaCP and https://certbot.eff.org/

What I know that request to /ws route is coming to node.js app (I am logging it). But it doesn't go to that handler

```
app.ws('/ws', SocketsHandler.registerWs);
```

In the end it matches with my last handler and returns 404

```
app.get('*', ErrorHandler.notFound);
```

The question: What it can be that WS library doesn't work in VPS environment but I don't see any error in console... ?

P.S. Localy I run app without SSL and nginx

```
wsServer.on('connection', function (socket) {...})
```

Comment: Locally it works with Nginx or without?

Comment: he says it does already @TarunLalwani

Comment: Did you change the socket url from `ws://` to `wss://` ?

Comment: Sure on https: I connect to wss:. If I didn't change it I would see an error related to SOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my config was overridden by some other file. So instead of Connection "upgrade"; server was receiving Connection "close"..